# Elasticsearch string based query to match a regular expression

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

I would like to know if it is possible to make a string based query to match a regular expression in elasticsearch.

I know it is possible the other way around (make a regex query to match a string in a elasticsearch document) but can I make a query based on a string and match a regular expression saved in the document with elasticsearch ?

For instance, I have a document filled with data including an input (the regular expression) and an output (describing the regular expression) as below :

```
{
  "input": "[0-9]+ ?kg",
  "output": "weight"
}
```

Can I make a query with the string "67kg" in order to match the regex and get this :

```
{
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "test1",
        "_type" : "type",
        "_id" : "XqXucGgBXOzlaMdqiLcI",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "input" : "[0-9]+ ?kg",
          "output" : "weight"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could achieve something like this with [Percolate Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-percolate-query.html) functionality.

Basically idea is the following, that your documents are the queries and you could search against them with your documents to see if these documents will be matched.

You need to create index with a special field type - `percolator`. For example,

```
PUT /my-index
{
    "mappings": {
        "_doc": {
            "properties": {
                "input": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                },
                "query": {
                    "type": "percolator"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After this one, add a document (which would be a query that will match your field `input` with a regexp)

For example,

```
PUT /my-index/_doc/1
{
    "query" : {
        "regexp" : {
            "input" : "[0-9]+( kg)?"
        }
    }
}
```

Also, you could for example try different queries here, depends on your needs.

After this one, test how your documents get matched again which query, by doing this:

```
GET /my-index/_search
{
    "query" : {
        "percolate" : {
            "field" : "query",
            "document" : {
                "input" : "67 kg"
            }
        }
    }
}
```